# How Can I set OnClick for the Ok button in Alert Box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stack, alert, mern

*I am Creating A systemtimeout functionality for my MERN App. I tried using React-idle-timer but unfortunately, it did not work. If someone can help me with that then it will be great too.*

**I tried another way to dislplay an alert box after a certain time. I want to create an OnClick for the OK button in the alert box.**
it means after the alert box will be displayed when user will click on OK button it should run Logout Function and redirect user to the login page.

Here is the code for useTimeout.jsx and I am calling Alert box in App.js Also I am adding Logout funcion whcih I want to add as Onclick of okay button

useTimeout.jsx

```
import {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function useTimeout(callback, delay){
    const stableCallback = useRef(callback);

    useEffect(() =>{
        stableCallback.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        const tick = () => stableCallback.current();
        if (typeof delay !== 'number') return;
        const t = setTimeout(tick, delay);
        return ()=> clearTimeout(t);
    }, [delay]);

}
```

This is how I have called it in App.js

```
import useTimeout from "./components/reactidealtimer/useTimeout";
 
function App() {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  useTimeout(()=> alert("Session Timed Out"), 10000);
  return (
```

Here is the logout Function which I want to add

```
function  logout(){
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location.href = '/login';
  };
```

Comment: `alert` is not a DOM node, so it doesn't have the [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) interface, meaning that you can't listen for events. Though it does block the code from running. Does expanding your callback function with `() => { alert("Session Timed Out"); logout(); }` work?

Comment: useTimeout(()=>{ alert("Session Timed Out"); logout(); })
this isn't showing alert box anymore

Comment: That's odd. Could you setup any way for us to run your React code. Like a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or any suitable alternative? Usually I would suggest a Stack Snippet, but that isn't the best application to run React in, IMO.

Comment: Yeah Sure
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/alimuhammad-creator/FYP/draft/wizardly-feather?import=true&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253Anull%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl7w6ot79000g356hcy9gtukw%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Atrue%257D%255D%257D

Comment: Looks like your snippet is still in *draft*. Try publishing it.

Comment: do i Need to install GitHub App?

Comment: Is there any other way to create Session TImeout for my App?
React-idle-timer isn't working

Comment: No I don't think you don't need to install the Github App. I don't believe you need `React-idle-timer` as your own implementation seems fine. If you do get your codesandbox running, please add the link to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Sure I will add this to the link once done